# Mongodb : can't find a table mapping for namespace database.collection

Tags: java, mongodb, android-studio, realm

I am trying to develop an android application withAndroid Studio in java and to insert data from a text entered in the application into the mongodb database, however, although the connection is carried out without problem the logs return me "Error:FUNCTION_EXECUTION_ERROR(realm::app::ServiceError:14): can't find a table mapping for namespace db.collec". I do however have a collection named collec in a db database.

Here is my code in java, do you know what is causing this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    User user = app.currentUser();
    mongoClient = user.getMongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
    mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
    MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("collec");

    mongoCollection.insertOne(new Document("userid",user.getId()).append("data",dataEditText.getText().toString())).getAsync(result -> {
        if(result.isSuccess())
        {
            Log.v("Data","Data Inserted Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v("Data","Error:"+result.getError().toString());
        }
    });
```

The error seems to be the same as here but I don't understand the resolution.

[MongoDB Realm Functions on React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905321/mongodb-realm-functions-on-react-native)

Comment: For clarification, do you want to do this task using the [Realm Java SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/quick-start-local/) or using the MongoClient remotely?

Comment: using the Realm Java SDK

Comment: Excellent! I suggesting reading over the getting started guide [Realm Java SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/examples/read-and-write-data/) and take a look at [Write Operations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/examples/read-and-write-data/#write-operations). Follow the processes in that guide to read and write data. *Use realm.createObject() in a transaction to create a persistent instance of a Realm object in a realm*